# Java: handler mandatory for checked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, checked

The java documentation says that it's mandatory for a checked exception to specify an handler that can "catch" the exception or to throws it in the method declaration.
But, if i do, for example:

```
public class DivZero{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   int a=10;
   int[] b={1,2,3,4,0};
   for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    System.out.println(a/b[i]);
   }
 }
}
```

It works fine also without "try-catch" or "throws" declaration. It throws a *java.lang.ArithmeticException*. So, it's not mandatory? The compiler implicitly throws the suitable Java "Throwable" class in the same way. It's so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) extends [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) thus it is not a checked exception. Checked exceptions are the ones inheriting from [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) but not from `RuntimeException`.

Quoting [JLS, 11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1):

> [...] checked exception classes are all subclasses of `Throwable` other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and Error and its subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

You have to catch only checked exceptions: sublcasses of `java.lang.Exception` that are not  subclasses of `java.lang.RuntimeException`. `ArithmeticException` is a sublcass of `RuntimeException`.

`RuntimeException`(s) usually signal bugs in your application, so you have to solve them, not to catch the exceptions. In your case `ArithmeticException` is thrown at line `System.out.println(a/b[i]);` because you are trying to divide an int by 0. You need to make sure that such divisions doesn't happen in your program.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of exceptions in Java: the ones that extend [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) are called [*checked*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions) and need to be handled (catching them, or throwing them) - for example, [IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html). The ones that extend from [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) are called [*unchecked*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) and don't need to be handled explicitly, unless you need to do something with them - for example, [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

For the code in the question, you can see that [ArithmeticException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) extends from RuntimeException, therefore is unchecked and you don't need to explicitly handle it.

Answer (score 1):

ArithmeticException is not a checked exception, thats why it allows you to compile fine.
Child classes of Exception are called checked exceptions remaining all are unchecked.